# Retrieving binary file from git

Tags: git

I know, committing binaries into git repo is stupid and generally considered a bad idea, but still:

is it possible to retrieve a binary file to some temp folder from git repo?

I mean of given commit hash?

Comment: `git checkout` works for binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: `git checkout` will check it out where it belongs, and `git show` will show it to standard output.  So if there's a tag `v2.3` that names commit `b6636ec88ba0750aec2706865653eb55031fb892` that ultimately contains the file `dir1/dir2/image.jpg` (which is a binary file), then:

```
git show v2.3:dir1/dir2/image.jpg > /some/temp/dir/wrongname-wrongext.gif
```

will put a copy of it in a file with a different name and extension, and:

```
git checkout b6636ec88ba0750aec2706865653eb55031fb892 -- dir1/dir2/image.jpg
```

(when run in the repo) will check out the version tagged `v2.3` (since `v2.3` is just a short name for `b6636ec88ba0750aec2706865653eb55031fb892`) into your work-dir under its normal path, even if the rest of the work-dir is at some other revision (perhaps a branch tip).

Edit (per comment): note that `git checkout` of a specific version and path will "write through" the index / staging-area, i.e., will leave the index with the file in `changes to be committed` state (as shown by `git status`).  If you don't want that, you will probably prefer the `git show` variant, which does not affect the index.

Comment: so when you checkout is replaces the file in the folder. Then you do reset it returns to the last committed version. right?

Comment: I mean you have to return the head back... how do you do that?

Comment: When you use `git checkout <rev> -- path`, git writes the checked-out file "through" the index into the given path.  So if you want to un-do that, use `git reset HEAD -- path`, or use `git show` to avoid having it written "through" the index in the first place.  Note that plain (aka `--mixed`) reset does not affect the work-dir version.